# How to deploy BIRT viewer 4.13 in the Tomcat-10

Tags: eclipse, birt, tomcat10

```
03-Aug-2023 11:31:49.000 INFO [http-nio-9999-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [E:\software\server\apache-tomcat-10.0.10\webapps\birt.war] has finished in [15,287] ms
03-Aug-2023 11:32:23.374 SEVERE [http-nio-9999-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
03-Aug-2023 11:32:23.374 SEVERE [http-nio-9999-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/birt] startup failed due to previous errors
03-Aug-2023 11:32:36.793 SEVERE [http-nio-9999-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
03-Aug-2023 11:32:36.793 SEVERE [http-nio-9999-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/birt] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I am founing these error.

BIRT viewer 4.13 deployment procedure for tomcat 10